# Authorize Spotify using React and Nginx in Docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, npm, spotify

I am building a dockerized `REST API` app with the following structure:

```
../
  web/
  nginx/
       dev.conf   
       Dockerfile-dev  
  client/
        build/
        conf/
        Dockerfile-dev
        node_modules/
        package_json
        public/
        src/
           App.jsx   
           components/ 
                     SpotifyRedirect.jsx                  
 spotify-client/ 
                Dockerfile-dev
                node_modules
                package-lock.json
                package.json
                authorization_code/
                                  app.js
```

---

> **NOTE:** In this project, user needs to go through **two** authorize/authenticate processes:

1. one with my app, which generates a native `token` (this has been dealt
   with already)
2. another with `Spotify` ( which requires a `redirect URI` and provides its own `token` for its API access)

   2a) So, at `localhost`, either after `localhost/auth/register` or `localhost/auth/login` submit, I would have `Spotify` `redirect URI` (`http://localhost:8888`), take me to this page:

[image]

2b) Then, clicking at the login button I would be asked to connect my app with Spotify, like so:

[image]

And with a last `OK` there I would be granted permission and handed a `token` which I could save and even refresh at my `React` client.

---

The building blocks to this project were extracted from this tutorial:

[using-spotifys-awesome-api-with-react](https://medium.com/@jonnykalambay/now-playing-using-spotifys-awesome-api-with-react-7db8173a7b13)

However, I already have configured a `React` `client`, which serves other purposes as well, apart from this authorization process.

The following is the relevant code which tries to integrate these two services: a more general `client` and `spotify-client`.

---

**Relevant code:**

So my first try was to create a specific service for `spotify-client`, below `client` service, exposing it to port 8888, like so:

> **docker-compose-dev.yml**

```
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./services/nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - web
      - client
      - spotify-client

  client:
    build:
      context: ./services/client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    volumes:
      - './services/client:/usr/src/app'
      - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - 3007:3000
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL=${REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}
    depends_on:
      - web

  spotify-client: // NEW
    build:
      context: ./services/spotify-client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    volumes:
      - './services/spotify-client:/usr/src/app'
      - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - 3000:8888
      - 8888:3000
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL=${REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}
    depends_on:
      - web
      - client
```

Then, I set each node process on its own `Dockerfile`, like so:

> **client/Dockerfile-dev**

```
# base image
FROM node:11.6.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add `/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@2.1.2 -g --silent

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

*and*:

> **spotify-client/Dockerfile-dev** // NEW

which has a different process running, as per required in `Spotify` web docs:

```
# base image
FROM node:11.6.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/authorization_code

# add `/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@2.1.2 -g --silent

# start app <-- NOT npm start
CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

My reverse proxy, I've tried:

> **nginx/dev.conf**

```
server {

  listen 80;
  listen 8888; // NEW

  location / {
    proxy_pass        http://client:3000;
    proxy_redirect    default;
    proxy_set_header  Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header  Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }


  location /auth {    // <-- app authorization, not Spotify's
    proxy_pass        http://web:5000;
    proxy_redirect    default;
    proxy_set_header  Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header  Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }
```

At my frontend I create a `component` for my redirect link:

> client/src/components/**SpofityRedirect.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SpotifyRedirect extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <div className='SpotifyRedirect'>
                <a href='http://localhost:8888'> Log in with Spotify </a>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SpotifyRedirect;
```

and here I show this redirect link at '/'.

> client/src/**App.jsx**

```
import SpotifyRedirect from './components/SpotifyRedirect';

 (...)
 <Switch
  <Route exact path='/' render={() => (
   <SpotifyRedirect/>
  )} />

 (...)
 </Switch>
```

More:

> spotify-client/authorization_code/**app.js**

(this is provided by `Spofity`, and I only inserted `http://localhost:3000`)

```
var express = require('express'); // Express web server framework
var request = require('request'); // "Request" library
var cors = require('cors');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var client_id = 'is'; // Your client id
var client_secret = 'secret'; // Your secret
var redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8888'; // Your redirect uri

/**
 * Generates a random string containing numbers and letters
 * @param  {number} length The length of the string
 * @return {string} The generated string
 */
var generateRandomString = function(length) {
  var text = '';
  var possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  }
  return text;
};

var stateKey = 'spotify_auth_state';

var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
   .use(cors())
   .use(cookieParser());

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {

  var state = generateRandomString(16);
  res.cookie(stateKey, state);

  // your application requests authorization
  var scope = 'user-read-private user-read-email user-read-playback-state playlist-modify-public playlist-modify-private';
  res.redirect('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?' +
    querystring.stringify({
      response_type: 'code',
      client_id: client_id,
      scope: scope,
      redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
      state: state
    }));
});

app.get('/callback', function(req, res) {

  // your application requests refresh and access tokens
  // after checking the state parameter

  var code = req.query.code || null;
  var state = req.query.state || null;
  var storedState = req.cookies ? req.cookies[stateKey] : null;

  if (state === null || state !== storedState) {
    res.redirect('/#' +
      querystring.stringify({
        error: 'state_mismatch'
      }));
  } else {
    res.clearCookie(stateKey);
    var authOptions = {
      url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
      form: {
        code: code,
        redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
        grant_type: 'authorization_code'
      },
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64'))
      },
      json: true
    };

    request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

        var access_token = body.access_token,
            refresh_token = body.refresh_token;

        var options = {
          url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
          headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token },
          json: true
        };

        // use the access token to access the Spotify Web API
        request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
          console.log(body);
        });

        // we can also pass the token to the browser to make requests from there
        res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/#' + //NEW
          querystring.stringify({
            access_token: access_token,
            refresh_token: refresh_token
          }));
      } else {
        res.redirect('/#' +
          querystring.stringify({
            error: 'invalid_token'
          }));
      }
    });
  }
});

app.get('/refresh_token', function(req, res) {

  // requesting access token from refresh token
  var refresh_token = req.query.refresh_token;
  var authOptions = {
    url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64')) },
    form: {
      grant_type: 'refresh_token',
      refresh_token: refresh_token
    },
    json: true
  };

  request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      var access_token = body.access_token;
      res.send({
        'access_token': access_token
      });
    }
  });
});

console.log('Listening on 8888');
app.listen(8888);

______
```

---

> `Docker` services at command line:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                            NAMES
0e9870a7412c        dev3_nginx                 "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   9 seconds ago       Up 6 seconds        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp               dev3_nginx_1
e6bc5bbff630        dev3_spotify-client        "node app.js"            26 minutes ago      Up 26 minutes       0.0.0.0:3000->8888/tcp           dev3_spotify-auth-server_1
a6b9e84953a3        dev3_client                "npm start"              25 hours              "/start.sh"              25 hours ago        Up 25 hours         80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3008->8080/tcp  
16fb623ca2b3        dev3_web                   "/usr/src/app/entryp…"   25 hours
```

---

Finally, before build, I run:

> **`$ export REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL=http://localhost`**
>
> ---

So far, with configuration aboce, when I click on [Log in with Soptify](http://Log%20in%20with%20Spotify), I'm getting:

[image]

---

**QUESTION:**

How can I use the configuration above with my `nginx reverse proxy` in order to:

1. Provide location **/** with a link for my `Spotify's` redirect uri http://localhost:8888
2. Authorize the app with Spotify
3. End up back at location **'/'** when authorization is all done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem: No container is listening on the port 8888. You can publish `spotify-client:8888` directly on port 8888 (without nginx). Update `docker-compose-dev.yml`:

```
 spotify-client:
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
```

If you really need nginx, then you will need to play with nginx config + you need to publish nginx on the port 8888 as well. `nginx/dev.conf` example:

```
  server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
      proxy_pass        http://client:3000;
      proxy_redirect    default;
      proxy_set_header  Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header  Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_set_header  Host $host;
      proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
    location /auth {
      proxy_pass        http://web:5000;
      proxy_redirect    default;
      proxy_set_header  Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header  Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_set_header  Host $host;
      proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
  }

  # reverse proxy on the port 8888 for spotify-client
  server {
    listen  8888;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://<spotify-client service/ip>:<port>/;
      proxy_redirect    default;
      proxy_set_header  Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header  Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_set_header  Host $host;
      proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
  }
```

`docker-compose-dev.yml` and nginx published ports:

```
  nginx:
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 8888:8888
```

Generally, you need to configure properly `nginx:8888`->`spotify-client:port`.

IMHO: you don't need `spotify-client` service at all. Just use [implicit flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#implicit-grant-flow) in your app to get Spotify token. It is more better choice for React/Angular (browser JS code). Keep in mind that refresh tokens doesn't exist in this flow, so you will need to implement silent refresh as well.

Comment: thank you. yes I really need nginx. could you please expand your answer in order to incluse `nginx` publishing?

Comment: @data_garden nginx.conf example included

Comment: thanks! both nginx and spotify-client allocated to port 8888? won't I get `Bind for 0.0.0.0:8888 failed: port is already allocated` for nginx?

Comment: also, when I rebuild it, I get: `nginx_1 | nginx: [emerg] "events" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/dev.conf:1`

Comment: I gave you 2 options: 1.) without reverse proxy, so spotify-client is published on 8888 2.) with reverse proxy, where nginx is published on 8888. Don't expect exact copy/paste solution. You still may need to customize it for your needs. I've updated answer - there is now dev.conf, not nginx.conf

Comment: one last thing...concerning item 3 in question. after authorization, app is not being redirected back to '/'. is this line in the code above (`app.js`) right?       ---> `res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/#' + `

Answer (score 0):

When you decided to use nginx you need to edit config and publish nginx on port 8888.